# Problem when running my code with python3 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, module

I'm new to Python 3 programming and are getting errors that I can't seem to fix. I'm trying to make a text editor.
This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class PyText:

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Untitled - PyText")
        master.geometry("1200x700")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.TK()
    pt = PyText(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

Running it I get:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "textEdit.py", line 12, in 
           master = tk.TK()
       AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TK'

How can I fix this??? Thank you for the help!

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. There is no attribute named `TK`. It's `Tk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `tk.TK()`, but you should use `tk.Tk()`, with small 'k'.
Also, you should probably use `self.master` in `__init__` function:

```
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Untitled - PyText")
        self.master.geometry("1200x700")
```

Then the link to a master object is preserved inside the `pt` object as `pt.master`.
Hope that's helpful!